# removing 'appendix'-prefix before bibliography in TOC

Tags: table-of-contents, bibliographies, amsbook

I have following code

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{amsbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \tableoffigures
    (z.B. Forster \cite{AN-Fo-01}, Schumacher \cite{FT-Re-01}).
    \appendix
    \bibliographystyle{amsalpha}
    \bibliography{bib}
\end{document}
```

In the TOC there is the prefix Appendix before the Bibliography. Does anybody know how to remove it (just for the Bib, not for other appendicies) and align it with tableoffigures?